# Adding a field to Categories?

Tags: meteor, telescope

I want to change the way a post list is rendered in Telescope based off a property of a category that its in.  I.e. One category is a ListView when another is a GridView.

I tried:

```
Categories.addField({
  fieldName: 'gridType',
  fieldSchema: {
  type: Number,
  optional: true,
  autoform: {
      omit: true
    }
  }
});
```

The issue is Im not seeing the property added, I also noticed in the documentation that this was intended for Posts, Users, Comments ect but I'm guessing it should work.

The reason I do not think its working is it's now showing up on the create Category Form

Comment: could you explain again what you are trying to accomplish? It's not clear from your question, at least to me. What is `Categories` and where do you define the `addField` function, and where is this being used?

Comment: Its a very telescope specific question.  addField is a prototype of the Mongo.Collection and Categories are an object part of telescope.  I ended up forking the repo and making all the modifications I want.  Still curious if there is a way to do what im trying to do.

Comment: oh, i see. Sorry, I didn't realize that and hadn't paid attention to the tag. I added some text to clarify that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the `autoform:{omit: true}`. It mentions in the docs that if you want to hide it from the forms you should pass the `omit` option, otherwise you can leave it out.

Also, be sure to add this in a file that's accessible on both the client and the server, otherwise you'll see it in the schema on the client with `Categories.simpleSchema()._schema` but it'll have to persist on the server.